# Asp .net application performance issues using JavaScript to open the application’s asp pages

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an asp .net application that is having a lot of performance issues. This application is a pre-ajax application. When the application is first displayed a default.html page loads and redirects the application to the primary asp page using JavaScript as shown below:

```
<script>
    handle = window.open('WebForm1.aspx','SecSys', 'resizable=1,top=0,height=' + (window.screen.availHeight - 35) + 'width=' + (window.screen.availwidth - 10));
    Window.opener = handle;
    Handle.focus();
</script>
```

Now in the newly opened WebForm1.aspx page an asp:GridView is defined that opens a new asp page when a row is doubled clicked. The way this is handled is in the GridView’s RowDataBound event the follow command is added to the e.Row.Attributes value as below:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add(“ondblclick”, “window.location=’WebForm2.aspx?id=” +  view.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].value + “’”);
```

Now, looking at how the application is designed and written using both the JavaScript window.opener and window.location methods could this be a primary source of the performance issues and if so is there a better way at implementing the functionality?

Comment: Where do you notice the "performance issues"? Is it when initially loading WebForm1.aspx? If so, does the GridView display hundreds or thousands of records on the page? If so, I'd say the perf issue is pulling down the records and rendering them in html on the client. If that's the case, I'd suggest reading up about implementing GridView paging to display a subset of all records in the GridView to boost performance.

Comment: Even though paging is being done in the GridView it takes several minutes for the grid to display. This being the case my next step is to do some testing with the database throughput. Because I have never used JavaScript to load ASP pages in this fashion before I just wanted to insure that was not an issue. Thanks for helping me to rule that out.